# How to find the battery recharge time of android mobile programatically?

Tags: android, battery

I wanted to know that how can we find how much time android device will take to fully charge its battery.

For example if my battery is 0% charged then how long it will take to charge full i.e. 100%, same if my device is 70% charge so if i connect charger now then how long it will take to full charge my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html) about this. Basically you'll need to use `BatteryManager` class to find out current state of battery level.

Comment: Creator Thanks for your reply,
i am able to find the battery level but i not finding the recharge time how much more time my battery requires for full charge.
please help me on this
thanks for your prev. reply

Comment: BatteryManager doesn't provide this information, but you can do it using simple logic, check what's the time last 1 percentage change took, and multiply that time to remaining percentage of charge. Since this time keeps on changing, you need to update the time/percentage frequently using a thread.

Comment: @noob how can i convert time elapse (msecs) in hours and in minutes

Comment: @ErumHannan you should ask a new question for this.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
private void batteryLevel() {
        BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                context.unregisterReceiver(this);
                int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
                int level = -1;
                if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                    level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;
                }
                batterLevel.setText("Battery Level Remaining: " + level + "%");
            }
        };
        IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
    }
```

See also: http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.de/2010/02/getting-battery-level-in-android-using.html

Comment: Good read, but he needs the time required to complete the charge. Anyways, Voted up.

Comment: As @noob said, this answer only gives a partial solution.  Shows you how to get the values but not what you do with them to get the time remaining.