# Using Power Profile can i calculate battery remaining time and discharge time in android

Tags: android, battery, batterylevel, batterymanager, battery-saver

I am new in android and i make battery optimize application.

I want to calculate battery remaining time and discharge time.

And i also want to calculate Wifi, 3G Call, Movie, Music and Bluetooth time.

I heard about powerprofile.xml to get wifi , 3G, video, movie and bluetooth time, So how can i use powerprofile to get this data.?

[Battery Used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlVVb.png)

Comment: @akhil Batlawala: Check this might help you!! -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/17772473/4018207

Comment: Sorry this will not help me.